# CPU issues after upgrade to Selenium V4.11.0

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, chrome

After using selenium 4.11.0 version and launch error for 116 browser launch error was resolved.

Has anyone observed Maximum CPU utilization issue after changing to selenium 4.11.0?

I was using selenium 4.8.3 before and I was not facing any issues. After changing to selenium 4.11.0 the CPU issue started.

Before my selenium version was 4.8.3 and chrome browser version was 115. My scripts worked without problems.

Now my selenium version is 4.11.0 and chrome browser version is 116. I did not change anything else. Is this a problem with the selenium version or the browser?

Comment: I have the same issue. It was related to version 116 of the chromediver. Edge and Gecko are still working the same. I upgraded Selenium from 4.10 to 4.11 and nothing changed. I also switched on the selenium-manager feature so I immediately get the new driver when it is fixed. The problem persists.

Comment: What numbers you had for max CPU utilization before and after?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution turned out to be **commenting out the "-no-sandbox" argument**. This was added years ago to solve a problem running the tests on an Azure DevOps VM. Today we use our own build servers so I don't know if the argument is needed for the original cause, but many messages discourage its use.

Comment: Thank you I refer to the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory#comment32164184_21320949" one guy suggested to use of driver.close(); and driver.quit() to resolve the issue. tried with this suggestion. In my current code only driver.quit() was used. with the update its working fine. The CPU problem was caused because the driver.quit() was closing the browser ideally it should as a result many browser was still running in background process(verified in task manger). but adding driver.close() before driver.quit() the issue was resloved

Comment: Thank you. I had the same situation. I added the Close as well.